# Calling java.lang.reflect.Field::getValue(this) from abstract superclass defined method returns IllegalAccessException

Tags: java, reflection, class-hierarchy

I'm trying to print the whole hierarchy of a class using reflection.

To do this I defined an abstract superclass A that defines the `toString(int offset)` method:

```
abstract class A {
    public String toString(int offset) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                builder.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(offset, "\t")));
                builder.append(field.getName()).append(": ");
                field.setAccessible(true); // workaround
                if (field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
                    // (int, float, ...)
                    builder.append(field.get(this));
                } else if (field.getType().getName().contains("java.lang")) {
                    // (Integer, String, ...)
                    builder.append(field.get(this).toString());
                } else {
                    // Other classes
                    builder.append("\n").append(A.class.cast(field.get(this)).toString(offset + 1));
                }
                builder.append("\n");
                field.setAccessible(false); // workaround
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

then I have some classes that extend the A class:

```
public class X extends A {
    private String field1;
    private Y field2;
}

public class Y extends A {
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
}
```

which instances contains some values.

The expected output of the call `x.toString(0)` should be:

```
field1: value1
field2:
    field3: value3
    field4: value4
```

Without the use of `field.setAccessible(true)` when I call `x.toString(0)` I get

`IllegalAccessException: Class A can not access a member of class X with modifiers "private"`

but I cannot undestand why.

When I check the reference while debugging `this` refers to X.class, so why the `field.getValue(this)` doesn't work?

Shouldn't `this` refer to the instance of the class calling the method? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

`private` doesn't mean it's private to the *instance*; it means it's private to the *class*. Inheritance doesn't offer any exemption from that (with the limited exception of `protected`). The following example would fail to compile in `A` because `field2` is inaccessible:

```
X x = (X)this;
System.out.println(x.field2);
```

Reflection imposes the same restrictions by default.